# File Not Found Error coming while reading the file in colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read in a csv file to work in google colab. Here is the syntax I'm trying:

```
#reading graph
if not os.path.isfile(r"D:\AAIC ASSIGNMENTS\AAIC ASSIGNMENT 17\Raw data\New folder\train_woheader.csv"):
    traincsv = pd.read_csv(r"D:\AAIC ASSIGNMENTS\AAIC ASSIGNMENT 17\Raw data\New folder\train.csv")
    print(traincsv[traincsv.isna().any(1)])
    print(traincsv.info())
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\AAIC ASSIGNMENTS\\AAIC ASSIGNMENT 17\\Raw data\\New folder\\train.csv'
```

I've triple checked the file name,changed the slashes and everything but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: Its humble request to all viewers, please try to solve this above problem

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1:

Testing locally, the `pd.read_csv()` function accepts a number of arguments (see [Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table))

In your code, try to change the existing line:

```py
traincsv = pd.read_csv(r"<path-to-file>")
```

into the following using `open()`

```py
traincsv = pd.read_csv(open(r"<path-to-file>"))
```

This generally returns a pandas object (per the docs), from which you can assign into a `dataframe` for example.

### Option 2:

However, it appears that google colab does not allow one to read file(s) directly from their local environment. Therefore, try the following bit of code:

```py
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Refer to the following [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-load-csv-files-into-colab-7c14fcbdcb92)

Comment: but this method won't work either

Comment: traincsv = pd.read_csv(open(r"D:\AAIC_ASSIGNMENTS\AAIC_ASSIGNMENT_17\Raw_data\New_folder\train.csv"))   Still gets an error

Comment: Try ```/``` in the path name

Comment: @buzzbowlekar - update answer with second option

Comment: traincsv = pd.read_csv(open(r"D:/AAIC_ASSIGNMENTS/AAIC_ASSIGNMENT_17/Raw_data/New_folder/train.csv"))        -  still gets an error

Comment: The second option should work, refer to the answer update.

Comment: Yes I got the answer but that took some time , so I find out the other way.....from google.colab import drive....
drive.mount('/content/drive/')  .....for this we just have to upload the files where the ipython file is present